# A single argument pattern definition applies to multiple-argument patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, rule, argument-patterns

Consider defining a pattern rule, such as

```
myFun[x_]:=x
```

As far as I understand Mathematica syntax, this rule means

`whenever myFun appears with a single argument, replace the whole thing by the argument`

Now, after the above definition, if we evaluate

```
myFun[x__]
```

> `x__`

we see that even though the pattern `x__` clearly symbolizes more than one argument, the single argument rule still gets executed!

Is this intended behavior? Maybe my syntax use is improper? How should I specify a single argument pattern rule which does not register with more-than-one argument patterns?

Comment: @kglr If I try to define `myFun[x_] = x` without the execution delay, I get the same behavior though...

Comment: In the second case `Set` has the attribute `HoldFirst` resulting in the same behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern `x__` is a [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern) object:

```
x__ //FullForm
```

> Pattern[x,BlankSequence[]]

While the pattern object represents multiple arguments in a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) or a function definition, it is a single object. Hence, your definition applies.

Why are you applying a function to a [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern) object, this is an unusual thing to do. Pattern objects usually appear inside of function definitions ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) or [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed)) or inside of rules ([`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) or [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed)).

Comment: My trouble is that after the `myFun[x_]:=x` definition, if I try to use `/.myFun[x__]->...` type of substitutions, the substitution is applied to `x__` instead of `myFun[x__]` which is mildly inconvenient. My workaround is to use `/.myFun[x_,y__]->...` instead.

Comment: @Kagaratsch `Rule` doesn't have any Hold attributes, so `myFun` evaluates. Typically, one works around this by using HoldPattern, e.g., `/. HoldPattern[myFun[x__]] -> ...`.

Comment: I see, very useful, thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to make `Rule` hold patterns by default? I tried `Unprotect[Rule];
SetAttributes[Rule, HoldAll];
Protect[Rule];` and it seems to work that way, but I get some weird error messages along the way.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Changing Rule in this way is dangerous and not recommended. It will probably break some Mathematica functionality.